# AWS SES: Stuck in sandbox mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I was ready to use SES for production so I had my sending limits increased. This is the email from AWS:

> "Congratulations! After reviewing your case, we have increased your sending quota to 50,000 messages per day and your maximum send rate to 14 messages per second in AWS Region US East (N. Virginia). Your account has also been moved out of the sandbox, so you no longer need to verify recipient addresses."

I configured sSMTP so I can send email using the mail command, using AWS endpoint and generated SMTP credentials. I send an email and I get this:

> "Oct 17 14:08:10 ia sSMTP[20486]: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: root , root@ia.internal.vdopia.com"

The SMTP endpoint is: `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587`

What am I doing wrong?

**Updated**
Output of `syslog`:

Output of `syslog`:

```
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: Creating SSL connection to host
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP       SimpleEmailService-1652178317 ANxvvoY79LhkdX5l8cYI
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: EHLO ia.internal.vdopia.com
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 250 Ok
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: STARTTLS
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 220 Ready to start TLS
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: SSL connection using RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: EHLO ia.internal.vdopia.com
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 250 Ok
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: AUTH LOGIN
--- removing some lines
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 235 Authentication successful.
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: MAIL FROM: <root@ia.internal.vdopia.com>
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 250 Ok
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: RCPT TO:<ayush.sharma@vdopia.com>
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 250 Ok
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: DATA
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: Received: by ia.internal.vdopia.com (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Wed, 19 Oct 2016 07:29:44 +0000
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: From: "root" <root@ia.internal.vdopia.com>
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 07:29:44 +0000
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: Subject: testing
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: To: <ayush.sharma@vdopia.com>
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]: X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)
Oct 19 07:29:44 ia sSMTP[427]:
Oct 19 07:29:45 ia sSMTP[427]: .
Oct 19 07:29:45 ia sSMTP[427]: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: root <root@ia.internal.vdopia.com>, root@ia.internal.vdopia.com
```

Comment: Is `root@ia.internal.vdopia.com` your from address?

Comment: I'm not setting anything explicitly, but when using the mail command, it sends it from root, and appends the hostname, which in this case is ia.internal.vdopia.com.

Comment: I tried adding Debug=Yes to ssmtp.conf and the debug data says there is no error there. The SMTP credentials are being checked fine, and it is only failing at the SES error I mentioned above.

Comment: What domain did you verify in SES? Was it `ia.internal.vdopia.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SMTP Response Codes Returned by Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html)

When your account is moved out of sand box, you do not have to verify the recipients' addresses. But you still have to **verify the sender's address or domain**. From your post, it appears you have not verified the sender's address. Remember to verify the address/domain that appears in:

- From
- Source
- Sender / Return-Path

Can you post your actual mail command/script that you are using to send the mail?

Comment: I'm using the following:
`mail -s 'testing' ayush.sharma@vdopia.com < /dev/null`

My machine hostname is `ia.internal.vdopia.com`

Comment: It worked! Verifying the domain is what I needed to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless this question is answered correctly, maybe this tip helps out other people. After the activation and switch from AWS SES Sandbox to Production mode (support request of limit increase) I realized, that using the old "SMTP IAM User" caused the same problem. Just create a new "SMTP IAM User" after production grant. I really cannot explain it but that worked several times now.